# seek_cur command sets the cursor in an unknown place in the file

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm

I have a file that contains one word on every line (the number of words and their length is unknown) and I need to rewrite those words into another file, starting with the last word and getting to the first one. When I print the last word in the file, I try to set the cursor (seek_cur) to seek for the next word, but it sets it in an unknown place. Tried printing the current cursor to see what happens and it gives characters like "@A".

The second jmp get_out stops the program after writing the last word, if it's deleted it gets to the jmp search tag and then it's printing the same last word infinitely.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;includem biblioteci, si declaram ce functii vrem sa importam
includelib msvcrt.lib
extern exit: proc
extern fopen: proc
extern fclose: proc
extern fscanf: proc
extern fprintf: proc
extern fseek: proc
extern fgets:proc

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;declaram simbolul start ca public - de acolo incepe executia
public start
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;sectiunile programului, date, respectiv cod
.data
file_read db "r",0
file_write db "w",0

file_name_read db "read.txt",0
file_name_write db "write.txt",0

seek_end dd 2
seek_cur dd 1
seek_set dd 0

caracter_format db "%c",0
string_format db "%s",0
decimal_format db "%d",0

string db 0
caracter db 0

back dd 0
first_word db 0

.code
start:
    push offset file_read
    push offset file_name_read
    call fopen
    add esp,8
    mov esi,eax

    push offset file_write
    push offset file_name_write
    call fopen
    add esp,8
    mov edi,eax

    ;in first_word se pune cuvantul de pe prima linie ca sa fie posibila comparatia mai incolo si sa se iese din bucla cand se ajunge la primul cuvant
    repeat_search_first_word:
        push offset caracter
        push offset caracter_format
        push esi
        call fscanf
        add esp,12

        inc back

        cmp caracter,0Ah
        je out_of_search_first_word 

    jmp repeat_search_first_word

        out_of_search_first_word:

        inc back
        neg back
        push seek_cur
        push back
        push esi
        call fseek
        add esp,12  

        neg back
        push esi
        push back
        push offset first_word
        call fgets
        add esp,12

        mov back,0


    ;incepe cautarea cuvintelor de la capat
    push seek_end
    push -1
    push esi
    call fseek
    add esp,12  

    search:
        push offset caracter
        push offset caracter_format
        push esi
        call fscanf
        add esp,12

        inc back

        cmp caracter,0Ah
        jne is_caracter

            push esi
            push back
            push offset string
            call fgets
            add esp,12

            push offset string
            push offset string_format
            push edi
            call fprintf
            add esp,12

            ;testam daca cuvantul coincide cu primul (first_word)
            mov ebx,0
            mov bl,string
            cmp bl,first_word
            je get_out


            add back,2
            neg back

            ;!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            ;problema pentru rularea infinita ii aici fiindca seek_cur muta cursorul intr-o zona necunoscuta din fisier 
            push seek_cur
            push back
            push esi
            call fseek
            add esp,12


            mov back,0
            jmp get_out ;linia 152 lasata fara comentariu permite afisare ultimului cuvant fara sa intre in rularea infinita a buclei
            jmp search

        is_caracter:

        push seek_cur
        push -2
        push esi
        call fseek
        add esp,12  

    jmp search  
    get_out:

    push edi
    call fclose 
    add esp,4

    push esi
    call fclose 
    add esp,4



    push 0
    call exit
end start
```

read.txt contains:

```
abc                          
defg                         
hijklm
```

write.txt should be:

```
hijklm
defg
abc
```

Comment: not the problem, but `seed_end = 2` to make it an assemble-time constant would make much more sense than loading a dword `2` from static storage!  Also, `fgetc` is *much* easier and more efficient than `fscanf(fp, "%c")`, and would return the character in a register where you could read it more efficiently than from memory.  Or you could use `fscanf(fp, "%s")` because `%s` skips whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string db 0` reserves space for 1 byte (initialized to zero).

You then call `fgets(fp, string, back)`, which will overwrite later things in your data section if it reads more than 1 byte (including the terminating 0).

Use a bigger buffer in the BSS, like a couple MB or something.

---

Use a debugger to trace function calls / system calls.  On Linux you could use `ltrace` to trace the libc stdio functions, or `strace` to trace the system calls they use.  On Windows IDK.  You can always step through and look at the args you've pushed on the stack before each call to make sure they're sane, but it's often easier to see a log-file style of listing when looking for one with the wrong args.

Comment: Changed the "string db 0" into "string dd 0" and it worked instantly. Many thanks!

Comment: @Kenshoru: uh, that will still break if you read a string longer than 3 bytes (+ 1 terminator).  Use something like `.bss` / `string db 1024*1024 dup(?)`

Comment: Noticed it eventually, it worked fine with 3 caracter words.. I’ll look into it. thanks !